# Identify the generated set $S$, starting from $1$ and $2$, by all $3x+y$ with distinct $x,y \in S$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

> A set $S$ contains integers $1$ and $2$. $S$ also contains all integers of the
> form $3x+y$ where $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $S$, and every element
> of $S$ other than $1$ and $2$ can be obtained as above. What is $S$?

Let's start by listing out some elements of $S$ that we can obtain using the given conditions:

- $1$ and $2$ are given as elements of $S$.
- If we take $x = 1$ and $y = 3$, we get $3x + y = 6$, which is an element of $S$.
- If we take $x = 2$ and $y = 3$, we get $3x + y = 9$, which is an element of $S$.
- If we take $x = 1$ and $y = 6$, we get $3x + y = 9$, which is also an element of $S$ (but we already have it).
- If we take $x = 2$ and $y = 6$, we get $3x + y = 12$, which is an element of $S$.
- If we take $x = 3$ and $y = 6$, we get $3x + y = 15$, which is an element of $S$.
- If we take $x = 6$ and $y = 12$, we get $3x + y = 30$, which is an element of $S$.

At this point, we have $1$, $2$, $6$, $9$, $12$, $15$, and $30$ as elements of $S$. We can continue this process to obtain more elements of $S$, but notice that any element of $S$ that is greater than $5$ can be written as $3x + y$ for some $x$ and $y$ in {$1$, $2$, $6$}, because any larger element can be written as the sum of two elements less than itself, and we already have $1$, $2$, $6$, $9$, $12$, $15$, and $30$. Moreover, if we choose $x$ and $y$ from {$1$, $2$, $6$}, then $3x + y$ is less than or equal to $3*6 + 6 = 24$, so we have:

$S = {1, 2, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 30}$.

Comment: Why do you let $y=3$ in $S$? Initially, you only know $1,2\in S$

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in [MathFail's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695806/identify-the-set-s#comment9936245_4695806), $3$ is not initially in $S$, and it can't be generated from $3x + y$ using positive integers. Also, the rest of your generated values, i.e., the multiples of $3$, are not in $S$.

Instead, note that for any $y_1 \neq 1$ where $y_1 \in S$, by repeatedly using $x = 1$ with $y$ being the latest generated value, we get $3(1) + y_1 = y_1 + 1(3)$, $3(1) + (y_1 + 1(3)) = y_1 + 2(3)$, $3(1) + (y_1 + 2(3)) = y_1 + 3(3)$, etc., also all being in $S$. Thus, as can be proven by induction, $y_1 + 3k \in S$ for all non-negative integers $k$.

Using this with $y_1 = 2$ shows that all positive integers which have a remainder of $2$ when divided by $3$ are in $S$. Next, along with $1$, since $y_1 = 3(2) + 1 = 7$, then all of the positive integers which have a remainder of $1$ when divided by $3$, *except* for $4$ since it requires $x = y = 1$ which is not allowed because $x$ and $y$ must be distinct, are also in $S$.

Note since $x,y \in \mathbb{N}^{+} \;\to\; z = 3x + y \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$, then since $S$ starts with just $1$ and $2$, then *only* positive integers can be generated to be in $S$ (i.e., it doesn't include any non-integral or negative values).

Finally, $S$ doesn't contain any integral multiples of $3$. This is because there are none initially so, if there were any, as all values in $S$ are positive integers, there would be a smallest generated one in $S$. However, because it must be of the form $m = 3x + y$ with $x,y \in S$ then, since $x \gt 0$, we have $y \lt m$ is also a multiple of $3$ which is in $S$, contradicting that it's being used to generate the smallest one of $m$.

This shows $S$ is the set of positive integers apart from $4$ and the integral multiples of $3$.

Comment: The minimal element property cannot be used for $3x+y$ because up until that point some $x$ can still be negative. I can't see where you've shown all elements of $S$ are positive.

Comment: @DerekLuna Thank you for your feedback. I've added some explanation which I trust makes it clear now that not only are all elements of $S$ are positive, but also that the set don't include an non-integral values.

Comment: It seems to me one would need to write some induction on a set sequence $x_{n}$ to address each iteration of the generation as in to set the generating set and the range as distinct. As in, ${1,2}$ is the first iteration, ${1,2,5,7}$ the second and so on. Then one could show that if for some $n$, that $x_{n}$ contains all positive numbers, then so does $x_{n+1}$, which only now becomes trivial after clearly defining this procedure into a nested function: $f(f(....(f(f(1,2)))...))$.

Comment: @DerekLuna Note I already explain in my answer how $S$ can only include positive integers, with it having all those $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, as well as all those $\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ except for $4$. Since I also show there's no integral multiples of $3$, I'm then able to reach the conclusion in my last paragraph. If there's anything unclear about any part of my answer, I can try to explain further. Re: what you wrote, I'm not sure why "address each iteration of the generation as in to set the generating set and the range as distinct" is needed, as well as doing the rest of what you're proposing.

Comment: I don't mean to address you specifically, maybe it is to help myself understand this better I am not sure. Personally, when I thought about this myself previously, I did not find the idea that because the initial terms were positive, that that is proof the entire set has all positive terms. I am not trying to be combative, I just did not find the reasoning satisfactory, but I must admit I don't always choose the best times to be pedantic.

Comment: @DerekLuna Thanks for the additional information. To be honest, I didn't initially explain that all of the values in $S$ must be positive as I thought this was fairly obvious. Nonetheless, what's obvious to one person is not necessarily to someone else so, as I stated before, I appreciate the feedback and have added an explanation about that. Regarding the rest of my answer, please let me know if you think anything is missing, unclear, etc., and I will try to address those issue(s).